# How to call base class method from base class when a derived class overloads it and the base class doesn't know that?

Tags: python, class, methods, derived

In my code, I define a class which is derived from another class out of a package which I cannot modify. I want to override a method of that base class which calls itself recursively in the base class. Unfortunately, this recursion now calls the newly defined method of the derived class instead of the original method of the base class. How can I tell python that the base class has to call it's own method and not the derived one without being able to modify this base class?

Example:

```
class Base(dict):
    ''' defined in a package, cannot modify anything in this class '''

    def func(self, param):
        if (not recursion abort condition):
            # The next line doesn't call Base.func() if someone overloads it in a derived class.
            # How can I achieve that it calls Base.func() every time, regardless of derived classes?
            # This class doesn't know that someone derives it at some time, so modifying it is not an option.
            compute_something += self.func(some_value)
        return stuff

class Derived(Base):
    ''' My class. Here, I have full access '''
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = <init some mutex>

    def func(self, param):
        # runs into a deadlock here in the second recursion call out of Base.func()
        with (self._lock):  # protect the method of the base class in some way
            return super(Derived, self).func(param)
```

Comment: You can't really.  If you call the base cass implementation, you can't control what it calls.  If you override a method, you need to make sure it works in whatever contexts it needs to be called.  If your overridden method doesn't work when called recursively like that, then either you need to write it differently, or you may need to explicitly duplicate some of the base class functionality instead of calling the base class version.  Why are you overriding `func` at all if you only want to change the first call to it (and not all recursive calls)?

Comment: Could you just use a recursive lock?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I cannot modify the lock either, it's also imported from a package.

Comment: func() is originally a write() function which I have to make thread-safe. It's rather long and can change with every package update, so duplicating it is not really an option. The closest solution I found so far is to rename my function in the derived class to writeLock() and to add some comment which omits using write() in threaded context. Crude, but works - until some other programmer from our team doesn't see the comment. Right now, I'm looking for a really pythonic solution.

Comment: don't *modify* the lock, use a *different* lock. a reentrant lock.